# linear regression after rotation

Tags: regression, python, linear, rotation

I have a set of 2 dimensional points [x,y], with a barycenter in 0,0 and I'm rotating it.

I'm wondering why the linear regression of this set of points is not rotating of the same amplitude.

Below is a sample python code :

```
#creating a vector with a barycenter in 0,0
vecta=myData-barycentre(myData)
#rotating it of pi/4
vectb=rotate(pi/4,vecta)

#coef1 and 2 are the coefficient of the linear regression : [slope,intercept]
coef1=plot_points(vecta,"green")
coef2=plot_points(vectb,"blue")
print coef1,coef2
```

> > [ -3.16058764e-02   1.71389357e-14] [-0.06893819  0.        ]

Intercept is 0,0 for both lines

```
#printing the result (I should get pi/4)
print atan(coef1[0])-atan(coef2[0]),pi/4
```

> > 0.0372339369372 0.785398163397

```
#showing the graphs
show()
```

[image]

One can clearly see that points have been rotated of pi/4 but not the slopes.

What am I missing here ?

Comment: Let's do some thought experiments. (1) Suppose you had a dataset of constant $y$ values, such as $(0,0), (1,0), (2,0)$.  Rotate it by $\pi/2$.  What result would regression give you? (2) Now suppose you had a dataset of $(x,y)$ values equally spaced around a circle in the form $\{\cos(j\pi/(4n)),\sin(j\pi/(4n)),\ j=1,2,\ldots,8n\}$. How much would the fitted slopes change after rotating the points by $\pi/4$? (Hint: this rotation would not change the geometry of the point cloud.)

Comment: It's certainly clear to you that the points have been rotated, since you did the rotating - but is it clear to the algorithm? It looks like your points have a rough radial symmetry. For the sake of intuition, let's say that we presented both datasets to a human observer, and told them to draw the line of best fit on each, without telling them that the datasets were rotated copies. What would you expect them to draw, based on the geometry of the points?

Comment: @whuber Thanks, I guess as I center my points arround their barycenter, I kind of create radial symetry on points. For these points a rotation might not impact the change in slope. I still need to think a bit more about it to figure out exactly how it works. if I'm not mistaken, even though for example 2 in your comment the linear regression stays unchanged, a mix of example 1 and 2 would lead to a rotation of the linear regression.

Comment: @LCialdella I'm still missing something, my result would imply that there are two or more solutions for the regression, and I dont think it's possible. May be the algo is taking into account something that i don't see. i printed these points completely randomly. What would be another day way to get the 'direction/orientation' of a set of points that varies with rotation ( when my set is not a circle), I was thinking of the sum of all vectors bit it seems too simple.

Comment: The orientation of a set of points is obtained with [tag:PCA] or its equivalent.  That is different than the least-squares approach you are taking (which is not appropriate for studying rotations due to the fundamental distinction between regressor and response variables).

Comment: @whuber, i will go for the pca, thx